# Question regarding how to directly apply softmax onto a logits with tf.keras.activation.softmax vs using tf.keras.layers.Softmax

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am completely new to this area so my question may sound stupid.
I have the following model defined using Keras, which takes multiple inputs and outputs to predict one of the 2 outcomes:

```
        inputs = []
        outputs = []
        for feature in features:
            length = feature.length
            input = tf.keras.Input(batch_size=batch_size, shape=(length,), sparse=False,
                                       name=feature.name)
            output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2)(raw_input)
            inputs.append(input)
            outputs.append(output)

        logits = tf.keras.layers.add(outputs)
        ##########################################################
        # Opt1: probabilities = tf.keras.activation.softmax(logits)
        # Opt2: probabilities = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(logits)
        # Opt3: probabilities = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(name="label")(logits)
        ##########################################################
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=probabilities)
        model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                      metric=["accuracy"])
```

I want the model to output to show the probability of one of the 2 predicted outcome, so I attempt to do softmax on the logits as output.

I have tried the 3 options, as shown above in the code (aka: Opt1, Opt2, Opt3).
Opt1 gives the following error:
`ValueError: No data provided for "tf_op_layer_Softmax". Need data for each key in: ['tf_op_layer_Softmax']`
Opt2 gives a similar error:
`ValueError: No data provided for "softmax". Need data for each key in: ['softmax']`
However, Opt3 runs just fine, despite that it is same as Opt2, except with a different name.

My questions are main the following:
1. In a Keras model, how do we usually directly apply a softmax onto logits without creating another layer?
2. What is the difference between Opt2 and Opt3, since its just a name change?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure, what do you mean by directly. But many layers have `activation` parameter which you can use to apply softmax.

For example, in a Dense layer, you can say something like,

`dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')(in_layer)`

There is no such parameter for `add()` so you can use another activation layer.

`softmax_out = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(in_layer)`

2. You have inconsistencies in your design.

`output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2)(raw_input)`

Where this `raw_input` is coming from? There's no practical difference between them, it's most probably just the way you've designed the network.

Here's the fixed version which works with Op2.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inputs = []
outputs = []

class Feature:
  def __init__(self, len_ = 10, name_ = 'unk'):
    self.length = len_
    self.name = name_

features = []

for i in range(5):
  f = Feature(name_ = 'unk' + str(i))
  features.append(f)

batch_size = 10

for feature in features:
    length = feature.length
    input = tf.keras.Input(batch_size=batch_size, shape=(length,), sparse=False,
                                name=feature.name)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2)(input)
    inputs.append(input)
    outputs.append(output)

logits = tf.keras.layers.add(outputs)

probabilities = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(logits)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=probabilities)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
unk0 (InputLayer)               [(10, 10)]           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
unk1 (InputLayer)               [(10, 10)]           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
unk2 (InputLayer)               [(10, 10)]           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
unk3 (InputLayer)               [(10, 10)]           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
unk4 (InputLayer)               [(10, 10)]           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (10, 2)              22          unk0[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)                (10, 2)              22          unk1[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)                (10, 2)              22          unk2[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)                (10, 2)              22          unk3[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)                (10, 2)              22          unk4[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (10, 2)              0           dense_17[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_18[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_19[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_20[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_21[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax_3 (Softmax)             (10, 2)              0           add_3[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 110
Trainable params: 110
Non-trainable params: 0
```